# What is the <project name>.sqlproj.user file, and how is it created?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to move a .sln file to a directory above where it is currently located (because right now it's in a project directory, which isn't semantically correct). The project is called 'pName', and within the project there is a file `pName.sqlproj.user`.

When i move the .sln file to the parent directory that same `.user` file is created. Why? is it due to which project is set as a startup?

Comment: Does not answer your question directly but talks about `.user` file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72298/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-suo-and-user-files-to-source-control